# Why does setting an img's width to a percentage inside a div ordered by css flexbox add extra height to the div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

You can see the extra height from using percentage for the width here *(in firefox)*:

http://jsfiddle.net/080xzqub/

And if you instead set a pixel width, it has no extra height:

http://jsfiddle.net/080xzqub/1/

Why does this occur? How do I fix this?

**EDIT: This occurs in Firefox**

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="a"></div>
 <div class="b">
    <img src="http://flamesnation.ca/uploads/Image/BlackBox.jpg" />
 </div>
```

**CSS with percentage:**

```
body
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;   
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
}

.a
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
    background-color: red;
}

.b
{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
    background-color: yellow;
}

img
{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
}
```

**CSS with pixel width:**

```
body
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;   
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
}

.a
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
    background-color: red;
}

.b
{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
    background-color: yellow;
}

img
{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is scaling it i.e. the ratio of width and height in both cases are equal. I think you have to define the height too

```
img
{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%; <- here
}
```